# Is there any possibility to change the way aws lambda invoke handler function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, es6-modules

I'm a new bee in aws and learning lambda function. I have written a handler function using node js es6 modules. To make it running I have installed babel and edited the package.json file as

"start": babel-node --presets es2015 ./index.js

when I added my code in aws lambda, it is showing exception as unexpected token type "import" which means its not recognising es6 class.

How can I change the way lambda function is triggered.

Can I pass custom command to trigger lambda function to execute es6 class in aws?

PS: I need to use only es6 class. Cannot use 'require' instead import.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own custom runtime for that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html

Another way is to compile the sources into a supported standard, even babel or for instance TypeScript can help here.

Comment: can you please provide a link to some example?